# I'm unable to detect idle time in Tauri app

Tags: rust

I would like to know if [Tauri](https://tauri.studio/en/) has an option to detect idle time, so far I've been unable to find it through their [docs](https://tauri.studio/en/docs/api/config). I've previously achieved this in Electron with their [Power Monitor API](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/power-monitor). So far the only workaround I've done is to use a webview and detect mouse movement, but this is not ideal since my application won't always be on top.

Comment: But if your application is not on top and you move your mouse over it, that would still count as idle, wouldn't it?

Comment: That's right, that why the workaround is not useful and not ideal

Comment: I'm looking to do the same thing.  Did you ever find a solution?  Maybe a better question is whether the current answer worked for you?

Comment: Turns out there is a cargo package for that https://crates.io/crates/user-idle

Answer (score 0):

I am still not sure what you mean with

> So far the only workaround I've done is to use a webview and detect mouse movement

but I suspect you mean, that you use javascript to detect mouse moves on the document. If thats the case you are almost there. You can detect if your window is focused in `wry = "0.10.1"` like so:

```rust
use wry::application::event::DeviceEvent;

fn main() {
    use wry::{
        application::{
            event::{Event, StartCause, WindowEvent},
            event_loop::{ControlFlow, EventLoop},
            window::WindowBuilder,
        },
        webview::WebViewBuilder,
    };

    let event_loop = EventLoop::new();
    let window = WindowBuilder::new()
        .with_title("Hello World")
        .build(&event_loop)
        .unwrap();
    let _webview = WebViewBuilder::new(window)
        .unwrap()
        .with_url("https://tauri.studio")
        .unwrap()
        .build()
        .unwrap();

    let mut is_window_focused = false;

    event_loop.run(move |event, _, control_flow| {
        *control_flow = ControlFlow::Wait;

        match event {
            Event::NewEvents(StartCause::Init) => println!("Wry has started!"),
            Event::DeviceEvent { event, .. } => match event {
                DeviceEvent::Motion { axis, value } => {
                    if is_window_focused {
                        println!("Mouse moved: {} {}", axis, value);
                    }
                }
                _ => (),
            },
            Event::WindowEvent {
                event: WindowEvent::Focused(focus),
                ..
            } => is_window_focused = focus,
            Event::WindowEvent {
                event: WindowEvent::CloseRequested,
                ..
            } => *control_flow = ControlFlow::Exit,
            _ => (),
        }
    });
}
```

Note that this example has the issue of also detecting mouse moves outside the window if it is focused, but if you use the javascript / DOM method of detecting mouse movements, it will work just fine.